# Git on Windows 7 for Android in Eclipse: How do I use version-control on existing project?

Tags: android, windows, eclipse, version-control

How do I take my existing project in Eclipse on Windows for Android and put it inside a branch on a repository for Git? I also want to share this repository with my friend to help code. He already set up a Git repository and sent me the address and credentials. I just don't know how to go about this?

Once I get a cmd line for Git on Windows what do I have to do to add/clone this project to my friends repo or my own (then how do I share my repo with him?). I use Git with GitHub in Ubuntu (I didn't set it up) but I don't really know how to set this up.

I've already installed a plug-in egit and have had issues with that. I would like to use a separate interface from Eclipse for Git now.

Bones of the Question: How do I get my existing Android project into a Git repository that IS NOT a plug in to Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download msysgit from http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/

Download TortiseGit https://tortoisegit.org/. If you're using private keys, make sure you select Plink instead of openssh.  I've had problems with OpenSSH for Windows.

Add your private key, if you're using it, to Pageant (included with Tortise Git).

Clone your repository with Tortise Git.

Copy all your files into the new directory.

In the Tortise Git context menu, select Add.

Select All

Commit

Push

That would be the short instructions.

Also, if you're comfortable with the command line tools, msysgit includes Git Bash, which is kinda like using Git in Linux.

Comment: What would you recommend for me to use my buddies Git setup? Thanks for this great answer though!!! (long instructions would be fine too, haha)

Comment: Your buddy set up a git repository and doesn't know how to use a Git client?  What platform is he working on?  My personal preference is to use command line tools and gitk when I need to visualize something. If he's comfortable with git on linux, all the man pages on kernel.org are great and they apply to Git Bash too.

Answer (score 1):

http://nathanj.github.com/gitguide/tour.html this is a nice tutorial on a gui version of git. in your case you would do a git clone from the existing url that your project is stored in or create a new repository if you havent set one up on github yet.

Comment: thanks for the tutorial but I'm not interested in using GitHub because it cost $$$.

Comment: if you don't want to pay you can also try http://www.bitbucket.org you can have a free private repo for up to 5 users!

Comment: That is using Mercurial (Hg) not Git.